# How to get tex4ht to respect listings styling better ?

Tags: listings, html, tex4ht

I've been producing PDFs and HTML from Latex sources, using tex4ht for the HTML (I'm on Debian/Lenny; so whatever versions are default on that).
I'm using the listings package to include source code.

I'm very happy with the "look" of the [PDF](http://www.bottlenose.demon.co.uk/article/lru.pdf), but the [HTML](http://www.bottlenose.demon.co.uk/article/lru.htm) looks a bit dreary without the code colouring or "blocked" listing headers.

Is there some way of getting the HTML to include more of the listings styling ?  (I'm not wedded to tex4ht if there are alternatives which do the job better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the effects you want by adding this to the HTML's stylesheet (Yay [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)!):

```
div.lstinputlisting table.caption {
    background: #c0c0c0;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-right: 100%;
}
div.lstinputlisting .pcrro7t- {
    color: red;
}
```

The [tex4ht page](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html) says you can achieve this by putting this into a config file:

```
\Preamble{html} 
\begin{document} 
  \Css{ // everything from above } 
\EndPreamble
```

From there I'll cross my fingers and hope you know or can figure out how to call the right tex4ht command and use that config file.  `tex4ht` syntax is a little weird but see the linked page for examples.

Comment: Thanks, that does the job nicely; new versions uploaded.  The '%' needed escaping in the .cfg file, and the '#' seemed to be causing trouble too but I used CSS colour names instead.

Comment: @timday: that looks very nice!